# How to make a Python Package without differenting files i.e other types

Tags: python

How to make a python package that does not need to be downloaded using pip and other ways.

I need to know how a package works in unity editor, so that i can use it in python.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I'm pretty sure this question has been asked before in this site (it seems awfully generic), but in order to point you in the right direction it'd be nice to understand it properly

Comment: Downloading is one option, you can install locally aswell

Comment: I will edit it and tell you. Actually i didnt find the answer anywhere else

Comment: Its different so i will edit it so that you understand

Comment: "Without pip" is just distributing a ZIP or egg file. If you want to package a full Python interpreter and python scripts (like Unity does), that is the only way you'll not need to download anything else

Comment: Question is still a bit unclear because [Unity requires an existing Python installation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.scripting.python@2.0/manual/settings.html), which you can install pip into Python2, but it is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages are different from GUI. To create a package, make a folder for example - Package1
.Then make an `__init__.py` file. You don't need to write anything in this. It can be empty. You just need to name an empty file as `__init__.py` and then place it in the folder.  `__init__.py` is just used for python to detect that the folder is a package. Then, you can place many more sub-packages or modules in this package.

Refer to this [Python Packages](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_packages.php#:%7E:text=A%20package%20is%20basically%20a,as%20a%20package%20by%20)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This helped me. I couldnt import without the `__init__.py`